# How to store results from a function inside the loop to the same excel sheet?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have for-loop listing multiple excel sheets , reading them, doing some processing and ideally I would like to store the resulting outputs into the same excel file/sheet.

the desired output is qs

```
files <- list.files(path = "V:/_190718AA_ascii", pattern = 
                      "*.xlsx", full.names = T)
df.list <- lapply(files, read_excel,col_names=FALSE)
kClusters=5
for (m in df.list) {

  qs[m]<- quantile(m[px[,,1,1]],probs=c(0,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95,0.975,1))

  write.xlsx(qs[m],"V:/_ORG/080-DOZP/BO-P2/DOZPLL/Esma/uqs.xlsx",sheet=m)
  m <- m+1      
}
```

it gives only the result from one m instead of 4.

Comment: It's difficult to help without example data, however when iterating `for (m in df.list)` through a list of data.frames `m <- m + 1` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you precise what is `qs` ?

Comment: Did you consider to do that inside Excel via VBA ? You can fire up R with the SYSTEM statemanet and fetch the reults afterwards. There are tons of VBA samples out.But nearly noone uses "R" with Excel;)

Answer (score 0):

`m` is not a number in your loop, but a dataframe. Additionnally, you do not need to increment it within a for loop.

My suggestion is to define m as number that will be incremented by the for loop. Not sure what is `qs`, so I've replaced it by a temporary variable (`temp`) for the sake of the example. But I haven't been able to test it as I do not have access to your data.

```
for (m in 1:length(df.list)) {

  temp<- quantile(df.list[[m]][px[,,1,1]],probs=c(0,0.025,0.05,0.1,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95,0.975,1))

  write.xlsx(temp,"V:/_ORG/080-DOZP/BO-P2/DOZPLL/Esma/uqs.xlsx",sheet=m) 
}
```